# How do I pipe the stdout and stderr of a process to the same Handle?

Tags: windows, haskell

How do I pipe the stdout and stderr of a process to the same Handle? On unix systems it's pretty easy, just use `createPipe` and pass the write end to `runProcess` as both stdout and stderr. On Windows it's harder:

- Neither the unix-compat nor the Win32 package export a way to create pipes.
- `openTempFile` (which could be use to simulate pipes) sets the wrong mode on the created `Handle`.

Edit: To give some more context: I want to run a process and have it write its stdout and stderr to the same `Handle`, in a cross-platform manner.

Comment: Interesting. In what way are the permissions wrong? According to the documentation, `openTempFile`'s `Handle` is created with `ReadWrite` permission, which ought to be enough for another process (run by the same user) to write to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use stuff from [System.Process](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/latest/doc/html/System-Process.html). In the `CreateProcess` definition there are

```
std_in       :: StdStream,               -- ^ How to determine stdin
std_out      :: StdStream,               -- ^ How to determine stdout
std_err      :: StdStream,               -- ^ How to determine stderr
```

and `StdStream` have this constructor:

```
data StdStream = UseHandle Handle
```

After that, pass the object you formed to the `createProcess` function to run your proc.

Comment: The problem is how to create the `Handle` in the first place.

Comment: Which `Handle`? Handle to stdout/stderr?

Comment: @arrowd Yes, how do you create the shared handle from where we can read both std_out and std_err?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing a cross-platform `createPipe`: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/tests/Distribution/Compat/CreatePipe.hsc

We should probably put it somewhere more accesible at some point.