# Haskell: System.Process merge stdout and stderr

Tags: haskell, process, pipe

I want to invoke a process from within a haskell program and capture stdout as well as stderr.

What I do:

```
(_, stdout, stderr) <- readProcessWithExitCode "command" [] ""
```

The problem: This way, stdout and stderr are captured separately, however I want the messages to appear in the right place (otherwise I would simply `stdout ++ stderr` which separates error messages from their stdout counterparts).

I do know that I could achieve this if I'd pipe the output into a file, i.e.

```
tmp <- openFile "temp.file" ...
createProcess (proc "command" []) { stdout = UseHandle tmp,
                                    stderr = UseHandle tmp }
```

So my current workaround is to pipe outputs to a tempfile and read it back in. However I'm looking for a more direct approach.

If I was on unix for sure I'd simply invoke a shell command á la

```
command 2>&1
```

and that's it. However, I'd like to have this as portable as possible.

What I need this for: I've built a tiny haskell cgi script (just to play with it) which invokes a certain program and prints the output. I want to html-escape the output, thus I can't simply pipe it to stdout.

I was thinking: Maybe it's possible to create an in-memory-handle, like a PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream in Java, or ArrayInputStream/ArrayOutputStream which allows for processing IO streams within memory. I looked around for a function `:: Handle` on hoogle, but did not find anything.

Maybe there is another Haskell module out there which allows me to merge two streams?

Comment: Perhaps [`createPipe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/latest/doc/html/System-Posix-IO-ByteString.html#v:createPipe) and [`fdToHandle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/latest/doc/html/System-Posix-IO-ByteString.html#v:fdToHandle) will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pipes` to concurrently merge two input streams.  The first trick is to read from two streams concurrently, which you can do using the `stm` package:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import System.Process

toTMVarC :: (Proxy p) => TMVar a -> () -> Consumer p a IO r
toTMVarC tmvar () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    a <- request ()
    lift $ atomically $ putTMVar tmvar a

fromTMVarS :: (Proxy p) => TMVar a -> () -> Producer p a IO r
fromTMVarS tmvar () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    a <- lift $ atomically $ takeTMVar tmvar
    respond a
```

I will soon provide the above primitives in a `pipes-stm` package, but use the above for now.

Then you just feed each `Handle` to a separate `MVar` and read from both concurrently:

```
main = do
    (_, mStdout, mStderr, _) <- createProcess (proc "ls" [])
    case (,) <$> mStdout <*> mStderr of
        Nothing               -> return ()
        Just (stdout, stderr) -> do
            out <- newEmptyTMVarIO
            err <- newEmptyTMVarIO
            forkIO $ runProxy $ hGetLineS stdout >-> toTMVarC out
            forkIO $ runProxy $ hGetLineS stderr >-> toTMVarC err
            let combine () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
                    str <- lift $ atomically $
                        takeTMVar out `orElse` takeTMVar err
                    respond str
            runProxy $ combine >-> putStrLnD
```

Just change out `putStrLnD` with however you want to process the input.

To learn more about the [`pipes` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), just read [Control.Proxy.Tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html).

Answer (score 5):

For posix system you can use `createPipe` and `fdToHandle` in `System.Posix.IO` to create a pair of new handles (I'm not sure where to close those handles and fds though..):

```
  readProcessWithMergedOutput :: String -> IO (ExitCode, String)
  readProcessWithMergedOutput command = do
    (p_r, p_w) <- createPipe
    h_r <- fdToHandle p_r
    h_w <- fdToHandle p_w
    (_, _, _, h_proc) <- createProcess (proc command [])
                                       { std_out = UseHandle h_w
                                       , std_err = UseHandle h_w
                                       }
    ret_code <- waitForProcess h_proc
    content <- hGetContents h_r
    return (ret_code, content)
```

For windows, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114952/how-do-i-pipe-the-stdout-and-stderr-of-a-process-to-the-same-handle) implemented a cross-platform `createPipe`.

Comment: Now, `process` package have `createPipe` action which combines `createPipe` and `fdToHandle` here.